# Integrate pagination component or bootstrap with Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, vuejs2, laravel-nova

I need to add a pagination to a Nova-tool I write.

The natural solution was trying to add the [vuejs-paginate](https://github.com/lokyoung/vuejs-paginate) component, but from some reason also no error appears in console, the pagination component is not shown.

So I tried to integrate bootstrap into Nova [as explained here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-integrate-bootstrap-with-laravel?page=1). The problem is that looks like there are css conflicts, for example the search box in resources looks like this:

[image]

Any solution?